# Request address for sparkDriver failing

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

while running pyspark on my terminal There is a new issue appeared in pyspark initiation:

> ```
> 17/12/28 10:31:59 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address:
> ```
>
> Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 0)!
>   Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service
>   'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available
>   port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.

I thought at first it's Java Runtime problem but it's not the case somehow spark driver is not able to connect to the host.
Any thought? help? suggestions?

Comment: did you added your hostname in  /etc/hosts if you are using unix based os?

Comment: You probably have another spark instance running on the machine. You can only run one spark instance because of port conflicts, unless you isolate configurations

Comment: The weird thing is sometimes it works and most of the time I am getting that error, it's blocking in spark appName while initializing spark context.
I am sure I have just one **spark** instance in my machine

Comment: the problem is VPN, I disconnected from VPN and everything worked, I guess because my host is localhost and that's why Spark Driver having trouble to connect.